# Speech recognition for Python 3.4 thats easy to work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I wish to get a simple speech recognition that works. I have been looking at this on speech_recognition, When I execute the code the following error occurs

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                
    audio = r.listen(source)                  

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    
except LookupError:                            




print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    # recognize speech using Google       Speech Recognition
AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize'

    print("Could not understand audio")
```

This was copied from their examples on their web page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem. The problem was that I had not set the minimum threshold level. So I added this code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()
#set threhold level
with m as source: r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
print("Set minimum energy threshold to {}".format(r.energy_threshold))
# obtain audio from the microphone

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Now its working perfect!!!

Answer (score 0):

What version of SpeechRecognition library do you use?

You can check it with:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
print sr.__version__
```

If you are using the latest version ([SpeechRecognition 3.1.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/3.1.3)), you should use a `recognize_google()` method instead of `recognize()`, to use Google API.

As for the latest documentation, you can look it up [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/3.1.3#recognizer-instance-recognize-google-audio-data-key-none-language-en-us-show-all-false), and also some useful [examples](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/#examples).

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a code that actually executes but fails to print out what I say

## NOTE: this example requires PyAudio because it uses the Microphone class

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
try:
    # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
    # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

# recognize speech using Wit.ai
WIT_AI_KEY = "INSERT WIT.AI API KEY HERE" # Wit.ai keys are 32-character uppercase alphanumeric strings
try:
    print("Wit.ai thinks you said " + r.recognize_wit(audio, key=WIT_AI_KEY))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Wit.ai could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Wit.ai service; {0}".format(e))

# recognize speech using IBM Speech to Text
IBM_USERNAME = "INSERT IBM SPEECH TO TEXT USERNAME HERE" # IBM Speech to Text usernames are strings of the form XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
IBM_PASSWORD = "INSERT IBM SPEECH TO TEXT PASSWORD HERE" # IBM Speech to Text passwords are mixed-case alphanumeric strings
try:
    print("IBM Speech to Text thinks you said " + r.recognize_ibm(audio, username=IBM_USERNAME, password=IBM_PASSWORD))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("IBM Speech to Text could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from IBM Speech to Text service; {0}".format(e))

# recognize speech using AT&T Speech to Text
ATT_APP_KEY = "INSERT AT&T SPEECH TO TEXT APP KEY HERE" # AT&T Speech to Text app keys are 32-character lowercase alphanumeric strings
ATT_APP_SECRET = "INSERT AT&T SPEECH TO TEXT APP SECRET HERE" # AT&T Speech to Text app secrets are 32-character lowercase alphanumeric strings
try:
    print("AT&T Speech to Text thinks you said " + r.recognize_att(audio, app_key=ATT_APP_KEY, app_secret=ATT_APP_SECRET))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("AT&T Speech to Text could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from AT&T Speech to Text service; {0}".format(e))
```

I get the following read out

**Say something!
Google Speech Recognition thinks you said hello
Could not request results from Wit.ai service; recognition request failed: Bad Request
Could not request results from IBM Speech to Text service; recognition request failed: Unauthorized
Could not request results from AT&T Speech to Text service; credential request failed: Unauthorized**